# how to collect contacts from different accounts

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook, curl

so i was wondering this: for example: when you subscribe to Facebook you have the option to invite your friends from gmail(if you have a gmail account), so you would enter your gmail login and password and facebook would grab all your contacts from gmail, so i was wondering how this is done? is there an API from Gmail or from Hotmail that permits to program this?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

These sites don't use an all-encompassing API, they take your login you provide and from *their* side login to Google (for example) **as you** and scrape it for your contact info.

This is why you should also be *very* careful about who you trust with that login information.

Answer (score 0):

yes .There r different API's for all of these.you can download them by simply typing contact fetcher script in Google or something like this. They r free.

refer link https://sourceforge.net/projects/contactgrabber

Comment: can you direct me to one of these API's ?

Answer (score 0):

There might not be an API specifically for it, but it's still pretty easy. I did something similar with PHP, using CURL to log in to a website and download reports automatically.

edit: You should be aware that some sites won't like that you do it, and might sue you for it. Always get a permission from the site owner before you try it.

Comment: @seed_of_tree: That's not an API, but a library doing exactly what I described. Still, it's nice to not have to write the code yourself.